# Parsing arithmetic expression with Haskell Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm writing a arithmetic parser to treat expressions like "1+2-3". I use [this blog post](https://norasandler.com/2017/12/15/Write-a-Compiler-3.html#fn2) as reference. To treat left associativity and precedence, I write a parser with Parsec according to this BNF (from blog post).

```
<exp> ::= <term> { ("+" | "-") <term> }
<term> ::= <factor> { ("*" | "/") <factor> }
<factor> ::= "(" <exp> ")" | <unary_op> <factor> | <int>
```

This is my parser code.

```hs
parseExp :: Parser Exp
parseExp = do
  t1 <- parseTerm
  loop t1
  where termSuffix t1 = do
          op <- lexeme $ oneOf "+-"
          t2 <- parseTerm
          case op of
            '+' -> termSuffix (Binary Plus t1 t2)
            '-' -> termSuffix (Binary Minus t1 t2)
        loop t = termSuffix t <|> return t

parseTerm :: Parser Exp
parseTerm = do
  f1 <- parseFactor
  loop f1
  where factorSuffix f1 = do
          op <- lexeme $ oneOf "*/"
          f2 <- parseFactor
          case op of
            '*' -> factorSuffix (Binary Mul f1 f2)
            '/' -> factorSuffix (Binary Div f1 f2)
        loop t = factorSuffix t <|> return t

parseFactor :: Parser Exp
parseFactor = parseConst <|> parseParen <|> parseUnary

parseParen = do
  void $ lexeme $ char '('
  e <- parseExp
  void $ lexeme $ char ')'
  return e

parseUnary :: Parser Exp
parseUnary = do
  op <- lexeme $ oneOf "!~-"
  f <- parseFactor
  case op of
    '!' -> return $ Unary LogNeg f
    '~' -> return $ Unary BitCompl f
    '-' -> return $ Unary ArithNeg f

parseConst :: Parser Exp
parseConst = do
  i <- many1 digit
  return (Const $ read i)
```

I also used this tutorial code as reference. [tutorial](http://jakewheat.github.io/intro_to_parsing/#_simple_expr)

```hs
simpleExpr7 :: Parser SimpleExpr
simpleExpr7 = do
    -- first parse a term
    e <- term7
    -- then see if it is followed by an '+ expr' suffix
    maybeAddSuffix e
  where
    -- this function takes an expression, and parses a
    -- '+ expr' suffix, returning an Add expression
    -- it recursively calls itself via the maybeAddSuffix function
    addSuffix e0 = do
        void $ lexeme $ char '+'
        e1 <- term7
        maybeAddSuffix (Add e0 e1)
    -- this is the wrapper for addSuffix, which adapts it so that if
    -- addSuffix fails, it returns just the original expression
    maybeAddSuffix e = addSuffix e <|> return e
```

My code doesn't work. This code works like this.

```
*Main CodeGen Parser> parseWithEof parseExp "-2"
Right (Unary ArithNeg (Const 2))
*Main CodeGen Parser> parseWithEof parseExp "(2)"
Right (Const 2)
*Main CodeGen Parser> parseWithEof parseExp "-!(((2)))"
Right (Unary ArithNeg (Unary LogNeg (Const 2)))
*Main CodeGen Parser> parseWithEof parseExp "1+2"
Left (line 1, column 4):
unexpected end of input
expecting digit
*Main CodeGen Parser> parseWithEof parseExp "1+2+3"
Left (line 1, column 6):
unexpected end of input
expecting digit
*Main CodeGen Parser> parseWithEof parseExp "1+2*3"
Left (line 1, column 6):
unexpected end of input
expecting digit
```

I can't understand why this results `unexpected end of input`.

Comment: Since you are using `parsec`, you may be interested in the [`Text.Parsec.Expr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Expr.html) module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider parsing `1+2`.  In `parseExp` this parses `1` into `t1 = Const 1` and then enters the loop `loop (Const 1)`.  The loop tries the first alternative `termSuffix (Const 1)` which succesfully parses the operator `+`, the next term `t2 = Const 2`, and then loops back into `termSuffix (Binary Plus (Const 1) (Const 2))` which expects either a `+` or `-`.  The parse fails.  Instead of looping back into `termSuffix`, you should loop back into `loop` to allow a single term after the first `+`:

```
parseExp :: Parser Exp
parseExp = do
  t1 <- parseTerm
  loop t1
  where termSuffix t1 = do
          op <- lexeme $ oneOf "+-"
          t2 <- parseTerm
          case op of
            -- *** use `loop` here, not `termSuffix` ***
            '+' -> loop (Binary Plus t1 t2)
            '-' -> loop (Binary Minus t1 t2)
        loop t = termSuffix t <|> return t
```

After making a similar change to `parseTerm`, your test cases all work fine.